# Addline of NotificationCompat.InboxStyle is not working

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-pendingintent

I am trying to make a chat application where my user will get notifications. The volume of notifications are so high, if I will make one entry for each notifications then it will fill up all the places, so I thought of applying BigTextView notifications or Stack of notifications.

I wrote below piece of code:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
        this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
if(listMessage.size() <= 5)
listMessage.add(messagetype + ":" + msg);
else
{
     listMessage.remove(4);
     listMessage.add(messagetype + ":" + msg);
}
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, GcmActivity.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra("title", messagetype);
notificationIntent.putExtra("message", msg);
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,notificationIntent, 0);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
        mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("My MESSENGER")
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText("MESSAGES"))
                        .setContentText(msg)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setLights(Color.WHITE, 1000, 5000)
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE |
                                Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS)
                        .setContentIntent(intent);

        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle =
                new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

        inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("MESSAGES");
        for(int j= 0;j < listMessage.size();j++)
        {

            inboxStyle.addLine(listMessage.get(j));
        }

        mBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);
        notificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

This seems not to add lines in the notification. it just shows the **setContentText** and it shows nothing.

Answer (score 6):

You may not have the expanded view of the notification. 
You need to swipe down within the notification (it works better with two fingers).

Comment: Also noticed that the expanded view will only show by default if your notification is at the top of the list of notifications.